# How can resolve the limited API number per second about the Debank API on the nest.js?

Tags: nestjs, api-design

I am trying to develop the back-end API using Nest.js and Debank API but I found Debank API is limited about the calling number per second. But I have to call a lot of API per second. How can I resolve this issue?

Debank: https://cloud.debank.com/#view-all-apis

I am using Nest.js `bottleneck` library for solving this issue, but I am not sure I am going to the right way.